# Difference between "transfer" and "network uplink"

Tags: networking

I'm investigating server colocation spaces in New York. On one marketing site, they advertise "transfer" of 10 Mbps and "network uplink" of 1 Gbps for $60/mo. What is the difference between these terms in this context?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Network Uplink is almost certainly related to the physical network port your rack or equipment would be connected to. A 1Gbps port would be capable of carrying up to 1Gbps of network traffic.

Transfer is almost certainly related to the volume of sustained network traffic you're paying for. 10 Mbps would mean you're paying for up to 10Mbps of sustained network traffic, probably billed at the 95th percentile. Exceed that and you'll pay overage charges.

**What you should do though, is to contact that provider and ask them to explain what each of those are as they relate to the services they're offering.**

Comment: Got it, thanks! And I'll check with them. There's still lots of research to do :)